# How to Bind Android TextView to Click event with MvvmCross

Tags: android, binding, textview, xamarin, mvvmcross

Is it possible to Bind Android TextView to Click event with MvvmCross?
Or as alternative make a button which looks like TextView?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is turned out that TextView can be bound same way as Button

```
local:MvxBind="Click DoCommand"
```

Comment: @AlexPetrenko: in your fragment 

var set = this.CreateBindingSet<YourFragment, YourViewModel> ();
   set.Bind (_textView).For (p => p.Click).To (vm => vm.YourCommand);
   set.Apply ();

Comment: it says click can only be used on left hand side

Answer (score 2):

You can bind a text view like this.

```
           <TextView  android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                local:MvxBind="Click DoThisCommand" />
```

height and width you can manage according to your convinience.
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

As the OP may be interested in methods to achieve click binding from code-behind as opposed to xml I have provided the following for guidance:

```
using MvvmCross.Platforms.Android.Binding;

var set = this.CreateBindingSet<theActivity,theViewModel>();
imageView1.For(x=> x.BindClick()).To(vm=>vm.imageViewClickCmd);
set.Apply()
```

The MvvmCross.Platforms.Android.Binding namespace provides the BindClick() extension method. Similar methods can be found for alternative events at the following links https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/data-binding#built-in-bindings

Alternatively you can use

```
    imageView1.For("Click").To(vm=>vm.imageViewClickCmd);
```